# Cannot implicitly convert type *** to ****

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up a GameObject pool in unity and i have encountered an error.

I am trying to save an object from a Dictionary to a new gameObject.

Please bear in mind i simplified the code for the post.

```
public class Pool
{
    public string tag;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public int maximumSize;
}

public List<Pool> pools;
public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;

private void UpdatePool()
{
        var objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pool.maximumSize; i++)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
            obj.SetActive(false);
            objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
        }

        poolDictionary.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
}

  public void SpawnFromPool(string tag)
{
    // the error is present here:
    GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag];
}
```

If i type:

```
  GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].Dequeue();
```

It works just fine, i can dequeue and Enqueue but this isn't the method i want to use. I would highly appreciate any help.

Error type: ***Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue>UnityEngine.GameObject> to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'***

Comment: Use : Queue<GameObject> objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag];

Comment: This way i'll create a new queue but i only want the object of the current dictionary's tag.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `Dequeue`?

Comment: I need the objects to be organised.

Comment: The dictionary is defined : public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictionary;  So every lookup of a key will return the object Queue<GameObject>.  A look up in a dictionary does not return a NEW object, just the object that was stored.

Comment: `I need the objects to be organised.` I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Yes, sorry, bad formulation from my side. It does return the object that was stored, it does not return a new object. I wanted (but failed) to point out that i need the object in a dequeued way without affecting the queue

Comment: I need the objects to be organised. I have no idea what you mean by that.

enqueue -> | 3 | 2 | 1 | -> dequeue.

The position in the queue is affected when i dequeue and enqueue because if i'm not mistaken, the dictionary uses a lifo structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said the problem is that `poolDictionary[tag]` is of type `Queue<GameObject>` not `GameObject`.

If what you want is retrieve the first element in that queue without using `Dequeue` (which removes the element from the queue) you can simply use [`Peek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.peek?view=netframework-4.6) instead

```
GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].Peek();
```

> This method is similar to the Dequeue method, but Peek does not modify the Queue.

---

To retrieve them all without removing them from the queue you can use e.g. [`ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue.toarray?view=netframework-4.6) and run through the elements in a `for` or `foreach` loop or simply access a specific one e.g. an equal (not in terms of overhead ofcourse) call to `Peek` might be

```
GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictionary[tag].ToArray()[0];
```

---

What I don't understand yet is why using a `Queue` if you don't want to `Dequeue` it ...

you could probably simply use a `List<GameObject>` than since the order of a `List` is also not changed (at least not without doing it actively)

If this is explicitly for object pooling (what it seems to be from the naming and spawning) you maybe should watch the [Tutorial on Object Pooling](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling) .. spoiler: They use a `List` ;)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! I use deque but I didn't want to use it in this case, i knew there has to be a more elegant solution. I do use deque in my pool, but, sometimes, i need to take the gravity scale of some rigidbodies (stored separately in different queues of the same tag so i don't have to use GetComponent). I need one float without changing the queue and this is the way to go.